# iptables ipv4 configuration for OpenVPN Connectvity

Tags: debian, iptables, configuration, openvpn, ipv4

I'm following this tutorial in order to setup my openvpn server:

https://linode.com/docs/networking/vpn/set-up-a-hardened-openvpn-server/

When i reached the part to replace the ipv4 configuration, and as soon as I did

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

I lost connectivity to the server.
here is the code I placed inside the file:

```
*filter

# Allow all loopback (lo) traffic and reject anything
# to localhost that does not originate from lo.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping and ICMP error returns.
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH.
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow UDP traffic on port 1194.
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS resolution and limited HTTP/S on eth0.
# Necessary for updating the server and timekeeping.
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic on the TUN interface so OpenVPN can communicate with eth0.
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

# Log any packets which don't fit the rules above.
# (optional but useful)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 4
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 4
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_OUTPUT_denied: " --log-level 4

# then reject them.
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

Any idea what is wrong with the above? it seems fine to me!

Thank you

Comment: So to be clear you can no longer connect to this server via ssh or as a vpn?

Comment: What port is your OpenVPN connection running on? I'm guessing it's UDP/1194, but I want to confirm this.

Comment: @kemotep yes i can no longer connect via ssh (vpn too early for this stage, haven't setuped the VPN yet, I'm still following the tutorial)

Comment: @ErikF I still haven't installed OpenVPN

Comment: @Jamesbrown, Can you still ping or otherwise communicate with the server? Is there a way to bring this back to before you pushed the new iptable rules? I would suggest starting over and making sure you can make changes to your firewall rules without losing connection. Start by just setting ssh rules or blocking ping. If you can line by line add and push the rules from the guide and you lose connection then you will not the heart of the issue.

Comment: Is your Ethernet interface actually called `eth0`? Most new installations are using [predictable network interface names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), which would change this to something like `enp3s0` or something.